# Routing is not working, I get Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

rake routes:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /user  devise_for :userss/password(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
              home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)             {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
                    root        /                                 {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

But if I click the logout link , I get

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

This is the application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  devise_for :users
<head>
  <title>Rorblog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%#= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">

        <ul class="hmenu">
            <li>
                <%= link_to('Home', home_index_path ) %>
            </li>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <li>
                <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
              </li>

              <li>
                <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
              </li>

            <% else %>
              <li>
                <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>
              </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
        <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
        <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>       
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="loadwhat">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <%= "user1@copyright.com" %>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

From page source I got:

```
<a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "rake routes" task shows the HTTP method that it will respond to in the second column. In the case of destroy_user_session_path, it only responds to the DELETE HTTP method. This is for safety as this is a destructive action, and different than a GET request. Ideally, web crawlers will not follow DELETE links because of their potential destructiveness.

As Arun Kumar Arjunan states, you will need to explicitly specify that this link should be executed with a DELETE method. By placing ":method => :delete" in your link, Rails UJS will convert this link to DELETE instead of a GET request, and follow the redirection from the server.

More information on HTTP methods here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

And more information on Rails UJS here: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery

Comment: Guru appears to have :method => :delete in his 'Logout' link.

Guru - What does the link look like in the source of the home page?

Comment: If Rails UJS picks it up, it will probably show as data-method="delete", and be intercepted by Javascript when clicked.

Comment: From page source , i got <a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>

Comment: No, i don't see any error from Tools>Web Developer>Error Console

Comment: Yes, gem 'jquery-rails' was commented in Gemfile, i uncommented that , now it looks ok. Can't understand why is it dependent on jquery-rails ?

Comment: It is a Rails convention that certain paths only respond to certain HTTP methods. This prevents destructive actions from being accessed by standard method types. HTML alone cannot represent a DELETE action, however Javascript can. This link conversion to a Javascript action is handled by jquery-rails, which is why it is a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Devise (at least in the current version) does not use DELETE, it does a GET for its 'destroy_user_session' path. So to logout, your view should only need a

```
link_to "logout", destroy_user_session_path
```

Your routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users
```

Here is my 'rake routes' for user:

```
new_user_session GET  /users/sign_in(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller =>"devise/sessions"}
user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```